# What are the correctness and use cases for two subjects for the same verb?

Tags: grammaticality, usage, poetry

This is found in [Bob Dylan's line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times_They_Are_a-Changin%27_(song)):

> The Times They Are a-Changin’

I would like to have an educated view on three aspects:

- It seems to be an artistic license, an incorrect form of *Times are changing*. Incorrect because of the two subjects (not using and/or), *times* and *they*, for a single verb.
- Is it how people say something is changing? Does someone using this sentence make an explicit reference to the song?
- Is it limited to spoken language or used in writing?

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong with 'the times'?

Comment: Dylan is 1. using informal rural dialect speech patterns 2. making words of a song fit the tune, so scansion and rhythm are important. In many dialects a pronoun (he, it, they, etc) can be inserted after a subject, e.g. John, he is a big man, my car, it is a-burning, the winds they are a-blowing, etc.

Comment: It's ***folksy dialectal song lyrics*** from 70 years ago! It's not really a suitable text for learning current English.

Comment: In spoken (not written) English, you might occasionally introduce a subject of conversation as an isolated noun or noun phrase, pause, and then follow it with a full sentence: "The war in Ukraine - it is still raging today."  This conveys a sense of thoughtfulness or perhaps strong emotion. It's more of a rhetorical flourish than a grammatical construction and would be more likely in a formal speech before an audience or a news broadcast than in casual conversation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 70-year-old folk song lyrics (that didn't remotely reflect mainstream natural speech even at the time) aren't worth analyzing for anyone seeking to learn *current mainstream English*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, So this is not the correct site to ask whether this phrase is grammatically correct, and whether it is used today? If so then close it, fair enough.

Comment: I don't think it's ever really meaningful to ask whether song lyrics are "grammatically correct". Especially not if your purpose in asking is to help learn English. If that's what you want to do, don't use song lyrics (even *current* ones) as a learning aid.

Comment: I just had a quick look, and my opinion is that's *not* a good place to use for learning English. But if you find the subject matter interesting, by all means spend time there - at least you'll be reading a lot of "more-or-less" normal current English. Just don't draw any conclusions about *current productive* constructions from an example that was specifically presented *because* it's "not normal English" (which is why it needs a bit of "explaining").

Comment: I very much doubt many (if *any*) people have said "The times they are a changing" anywhere in the world in the last 50 years, *unless* they're deliberately quoting the line from the song. Personally, I'd have though [***plus ça change***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plus_%C3%A7a_change) would have been said more often anyway (but you won't learn much about English from that one either! :)

Comment: This is actually a phenomenon called "left dislocation". If you edit the question to ask specifically about "the times they" (which might appear to be a double subject), I'd be happy to write out an answer. Writing "is there more to understand about this use?" appears to invite speculation, which might be why you've gotten some close votes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If maths isn't an opinion, the song/poem was composed a mere *59 years ago* (cough, cough). Does that make the entire song obsolete? OK, then maybe it's only the title? This literary device, and smart observation by the OP,  is found in English today.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Those lyrics were quaint / antiquated / dialectal when they were written! Unless I'm much mistaken, prefix ***a-*** hasn't been "productive" for centuries, and it's definitely "non-standard" in Dylan's ***a-changing*** context.

Comment: [**The times they are a-changin’**: *a proposal on how brain flexibility goes beyond the obvious to include the concepts of “upward” and “downward” to neuroplasticity*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41380-022-01931-x) and [*To this end, now is the time for all of us with ties to the E&F community to take a step back and recognize that, **‘the times they are a-changin’***](https://www.kkr.com/global-perspectives/publications/the-times-they-are-a-changin)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The phrase is often used by the media, especially by the American press for obvious reasons. Here's another citation (2023) [The Times They Are A Changin‘, Says Bill Maher On ’Real Time’ – The New York Newspaper, That Is](https://deadline.com/2023/02/the-times-they-are-a-changin-says-bill-maher-on-real-time-new-york-newspaper-he-meant-1235263985/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: The fact that people still *quote* the song title doesn't imply learners have anything to gain from having the syntax explained to them. Just as it is with various Lain phrases that Anglophones still use - without needing to study Latin vocabulary or grammar.

Comment: Fair comment but learners might ask themselves why a "they are" is inserted in that iconic phrase. And they might be curious to know if it is commonly used in speech or writing by native speakers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Not only in the media, also on [.gov and .edu institutional sites](https://www.google.com/search?q="the+times+they+are+a+changin"+-"dylan"+(site:.gov+OR+site:.edu)&complete=0) which I certainly won't suspect of using obsolete dialects ([random sample](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35004965/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to be an artistic license, an incorrect form of Times are changing. Incorrect because of the two subjects (not using and/or), times and they, for a single verb.

This is an example of "left dislocation", a common (though often informal) construction in English. The "normal" sentence would be:

> The times are a-changin'.

Huddleston & Pullum write (with some light editing by me):

> A dislocated clause has a constituent, usually a noun phrase, located to the left or right of the nucleus of the clause, with a linked pronoun or comparable form within the nucleus itself. Compare:
>
> i *Her parents seem pretty uncaring.* [non-dislocated version]
> ii *Her parents, they seem pretty uncaring.* [left dislocation]
>
> (Huddleston & Pullum, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, pg. 1411)

Note that it is common to include a comma between the dislocated noun phrase and the nucleus. I'm not sure why Dylan didn't do so.

---

> Is it how people say something is changing? Does someone using this sentence make an explicit reference to the song?

People do sometimes use this exact phrase, and in such cases most listeners (or readers) understand that it is a reference to Dylan's song, which is very famous.

---

Is it limited to spoken language or used in writing?

According to [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=629),

> Left dislocation is certainly grammatical in English. Up to 1500 or so, roughly one in every 100 or 200 sentences had this form, even in formal writing, and a similar frequency of use continues in spoken English to this day. Over the past few centuries, the frequency of this construction in standard written English has been declining, and it's now quite rare except in archaic styles, in representations of speech, or in informal styles that use spoken-language norms.

Comment: @mins Yes, in English LD is most often used for subjects, but it can also be used for other functions, such as in this example from that Language Log post: "The Saturns, you can get air bags in them."